# Irrealis conditional versus possibility

Tags: word-usage, tenses, conditional-mood

In English, the following sentences have a different meaning.

> If I were rich, I would live on Long Island.

> If I am late, it is because the bus is late.

While the first sentence is using the irrealis mood, and it expresses something that will never happen (I will never be rich, and I will never live on Long Island), the second sentence is expressing a possibility (in the case I am late, that is because the bus is late).

Is there a way to express that also in Italian? Can I express the difference there is in those English sentences also in Italian, using two different moods or tenses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just as for English, the same distinction can be done in Italian, using the subjunctive + conditional vs the indicative.

> Se **fossi** ricco **vivrei** su Long Island. (present subjunctive + present conditional)

or, in the past

> Se **fossi stato** ricco **avrei vissuto** su Long Island.

versus

> Se **sono** in ritardo **è** a causa del [ritardo del] bus (present indicative)

or, in the past

> Se **fui** in ritardo **fu** a causa del bus